# Add to queue button Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is there a way to add ADD TO QUEUE button on a form in a custom entity? I want to have my own ticketing entity and forms and autonumbering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. you must use Ribbon Workbench. And generally, you will want to have knowledge of javascript because you will often use javascript to perform your customizations with your button.

https://www.develop1.net/public/rwb/ribbonworkbench.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must activate the queue management on this entity and you will automatically have the button "add to the queue" on your entity

[image]